# Gnome uses qt for rendering

Tags: gnome, kde

I've just installed KDE on my Ubuntu 12.04 (sudo apt-get install kde-full).

Normally I use Gnome (not Unity), but after installation of KDE i see that the rendering was changed. Everything looks like it was rendered by QT, not GTK.

So my question is how to check which rendering engine is being used (QT or GTK)? And how to change it?

Comment: Did you select "Unity" as the interface of your choice, from the login screen? Also please add a relevant screenshot. That can help a lot.

Comment: @saji89 "Normally I use Gnome (not Unity)"

Comment: Yes, that's correct I prefer Gnome over Unity. However I have all 3 desktops installed: Unity, Gnome and KDE.

Comment: Please update your question with (partial) screenshots and mention all applications that seem "ugly" now (and which don't).

Comment: So did you make the selection "Gnome" as your chosen interface, from the login screen?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you were probably using Qt applications (you didn't mention which, so can't check really), rendered in a GTK theme before. Now, they're rendered in a native theme.

Install the QtConfig tool to change this:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
```

And run it:

```
qtconfig
```

Then change your setting here:

[image]

Comment: I've just checked proposed solution, however it looks like it didn't do the job. It looks like native gnome rendering engine has been changed. Every menu, context menu and so on looks like it was rendered by KDE not GNOME (however I'm using also GTK application - for example Eclipse).

Comment: @altanis Eclipse isn't GTK afaik, it's a Java GUI framework with a skin.

Comment: Here is Eclipse launcher I'm using: plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813. The name strongly suggests GTK.

Comment: eclipse uses [SWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit) which is pretty dependent on the underlying user library. Even though SWT has Motif support, I don't think you can use it, and it wouldn't gain you much since Motif isn't Qt either.