# KDE overrides lightdm logon screen

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, kdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install KDE and retain LightDM as a login manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146320/how-do-i-install-kde-and-retain-lightdm-as-a-login-manager)

I upgraded my KDE desktop and suddenly it overrode many parts of unity user interface such as menus, icons, and specifically (in this question) lightDM login screen.

here is a screenshot of menus:
[image]

how should i fix this?

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/q/225600/44179

Comment: @gertvdijk no, it's not duplicate, my os did not switch to KDM, i had kdm and lightDM but both looked the same. ( Not exactly the same but they were KDE-styled! i hope i could say clearly what i mean)

Comment: @EBi Okay, that makes it clear. Removed my comment. Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/244564/88802) help you out?

Answer (score 1):

I accidently solved one part of [one of my questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234488/kde-plasma-styled-menu-and-ui-in-unity-problem).

To fix login screen problem (lightDM):
At first it may not be overridden and just switched to kdm. Enter this command in terminal:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Hit enter to enter the menu. Select `light-dm` or `gdm` instead of kdm and hit enter again. logout or reboot to see if it's fixed.

If the problem persists it means that kde changed the theme of lightdm. Enter this command in terminal: `sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and change/add these lines:

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
```

save the file, `sudo reboot`, enjoy!

Comment: (About revision history):  Not all questions get answers instantly, you have to wait sometimes.

Comment: I read about this in the chat room and don't follow what's going on here. Why is EBi providing an answer here to a question asked elsewhere?

Comment: I also don't see how this answers the question here. EBi clearly states to have an issue with application in Unity and that his issue is not about a login screen problem.